# Plus.Activities.Search.execute() throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/api/urlfetch/HTTPMethod

Tags: java, google-plus, google-client

Using the 1.17 rc version of the google api client and the services plus I get a `ClassDefFoundError` whenever I execute the following code:

```
Plus.Activities.Search req = service.activities().search(q); 
ActivityFeed feed = req.execute();
```

Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/api/urlfetch/HTTPMethod
at com.google.api.client.extensions.appengine.http.UrlFetchTransport.buildRequest(UrlFetchTransport.java:125)
at com.google.api.client.extensions.appengine.http.UrlFetchTransport.buildRequest(UrlFetchTransport.java:51)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:863)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:283)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.executeRefreshToken(Credential.java:570)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:248)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:217)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:859)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
at googleplus.GPGet.SearchActivities(GPGet.java:70)
at googleplus.GPGet.main(GPGet.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPMethod
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
... 15 more
```

Comment: There are files which were present at compilation but not at runtime. Find them and add them to the -classpath

Comment: Doesn't netbeans do this automatically when you have added the libraries?

Comment: If you are running from netbeans, it should. Unless you are trying to load classes at runtime (which doesn't look like what you're trying to do, unless you're doing something weird involving sending objects over network), that is still the only reason this error would be produced. It might be a library which the google API library is dependent upon but which you failed to download; you can check for that.

Comment: This might be caused by not putting the Google libraries in the "libs" directory, according to this: [https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Setup

Comment: I solved the same error by copying `SDK/lib/user/appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.27.jar` into my project's `WEB-INF/lib` folder.